# custom-toggler in Bootstrap 4. Can't change the background color nor the border color

Tags: css, customization, hamburger-menu

Sorry folks, I'm such a novice. Bootstrap 4 in Dreamweaver.

Through trial an error, and some help on here, I have managed to fix most of my problems.

Now, for the custom toggler. I found where I can change the color. But it seems only some of the color.

I got the lines yellow, but I can't make the border yellow, nor can I make the button background #0A0A0A.

It looks to me as though I have followed the guidelines I found, but maybe some of my trial and error fouled things up? [screenshot of little hamburger with yellow lines, blue border and white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUuXh.png)

Here is the CSS I used:

```
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {

background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(243,203,4,1)' stroke-width='3' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");

}

//change toggler color

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #ffcc00;
}
    
//end change toggler color but I need to change the toggler bg color

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover, .navbar-toggler:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
 </head>
  <body>
<div class="container align-content-center"><img src="images/banner7.png" alt="" width="100%" lass="img-fluid"/></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-custom navbar-custom">
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
              <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
```

Do I need to duplicate and tweek all the instances for nav-light and/or nav-dark to make a complete nav-custom set?

I swear I'll go study more on W3 schools, but I'm really anxious to get this site up soon so I can make a better impression in my job search.

Thanks,
Clare

Answer (score 1):

Overall, you only have to add two custom classes to your button to change the toggler SVG styling:

```
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   border-color: #f3cb06;
   background-color: #0A0A0A;
} 

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(243,203,6,1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

Don't forget to add the custom class to your html:

i.e.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-toggler" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

If you'd also like to change the button outline, modify the `button:focus` class.

example 1.

```
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;  
outline: revert; 
}
```

or

example 2

```
button:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline-style:ridge;
  outline-color: grey;
}
```

―

Add `border-radius: 0.25rem;` to `.navbar-toggler` to get those rounded corners back.

```
.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

To get rid of the white outline replace `.button:focus` with the example 2:

```
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;  
  outline: revert; 
}
```

Comment: Good morning, Ripperdoc!
Thanks again. You are a lifesaver! I swear I will go learn more on W3 when I have published this. I haven't built a site in 10 years. Only maintained them. A lot has changed since then. Now, being laid off, I need to present myself with the current technology. 

I really appreciate your help.

One question... (in the answer block because screenshots won't go in a reply)...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Bootstrap 5,

- I just copy line `.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon{` (unless you chose `.navbar-dark`) from bootstrap.css file (line 4203),
- And paste to my own `style.css` file.
- And changed the rgb color in the url line and add `!important`.
- Additionally I changed color and border color in `.navbar-light .navbar-toggler{` (line 4199) also in my own css file.

You can see screenshot:

[image: here]